# Project 'Projr' is not up to date. Missing output file 'c:\..\bin\Debug\Projr.dll' in VS 2017 Administrator mode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have been stuck with this issue from the past 2 days **blank class library project**;

- I tried restarting VS 2017 Professional edition
- Restarting my Machine.
- Reinstalled VS 2017 with the latest available update.

Still facing the issue.

Whenever we build the project it gives me the below message in the output window: no error in error list even checked the "Build Only" option in Error list - no error;
**Project 'Projr' is not up to date. Missing output file 'c:..\bin\Debug\Projr.dll'**

One thing I noticed is:

- I open my VS2017 as Administrator permission(Run As Admin)- gives me this issue.
- But if I open without this admin option- I will be able to build my project. Since my project is a web project, I need this to be binded with IIS and virtual directory, so I need Admin mode.

Note: the project now am trying to build(test project) is a blank class library project which is created in VS 2017 itself, **this cannot be successfully built on Administrator mode**.

Can anyone help me with this issue.?

**Edit1**:
From output window message in  Admin mode;

1>Project 'Projr' is not up to date. Missing output file 'c:..\bin\Debug\Projr.dll'.
1>------ Build started: Project: Projr, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

**Edit2**:
After trying this suggestion by Alexander & Jeremy
Clean the solution(**This is failing for me**), close solution and VS also.
Then delete the SUO file and bin and obj folders.
Open VS.
Re-ref the DLL, etc, etc.. Change ref path in csproj file(s).(no special DLLs other than MS libraries. Its a blank brand new class library project.)

**Edit3**: Cannot build on VS2017 Admin mode but can build on developer CMD Admin mode.

Comment: Check that the Project Dependencies are correct. Check that the Web Project is selected as the Startup Project when you (Re)Build.

Comment: I have only 1 project in this solution, that is blank class library project and which is new project i have created to check whats wrong happening with my visual studio build functionality. If this started working i would like to try on my actual web project. But even this is failing with this issue.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645316/visual-studio-2015-doesnt-detect-built-project-looks-for-output-in-wrong-direc

Comment: Clean solution is also failing for me, and no special DLLs other than MS libraries referred. Its a blank brand new class library project in VS 2017.

Comment: This is your project? No one else can repro this issue on different machines? Any custom scripts being executed from within the .csproj (right-click the .csproj and view as text)? New .csprojs are able to be built as expected? Have you tried moving the project/.sln to a thumb drive? Copy applicable code into a new .sln/.csproj that builds correctly?

Comment: This is a blank class library project, so i think all the projects will show these error on build on Admin mode.

Comment: if this is blank project, have you tried to remove it and add new blank project in admin mode? With clean inbetween?

Comment: Why is it searching a file on your C:/ drive root? Missing output file 'c:\bin\Debug\Projr.dll' Have you modified the outputpath? I the c:\bin\Debug already bound to a running app pool in IIS? The files might be stuck because of the process.

Comment: This project is too "blank", c:\bin\debug is not correct.  At least use the correct project template to get started, ensure that picking Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Core Web Application gives you something that you can run.  If not then you have to go back to the installer and pick the right workload.

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek i clean the solution(failed) and removed the current project, and then added new class library project, still gives me the build error.

Comment: In VS 2017 Admin is creating bin\debug and obj\debug but not creating the dll file.. I just tried- the developer command prompt in Admin mode is creating the dll as expected and showing build succeeded..

Comment: Hi, I've come across this error previously, in my case, it was because another program was using the dll, i.e, the dll was being used the previously built solution, so I had to stop the application and then build the solution again, worked for me!

Comment: Is Projr the name of the new project?  Seems to me like running as 'Admin' will cause VS to pull the new project template from a different location (perhaps: C:\Users\Default\Documents\Visual Studio xxxx\Templates\).  Maybe someone has mucked with those templates and added a dependency to the project template.  Try deleting that folder and copy the similar folder from your user directory there??

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/obtaining-build-logs-with-msbuild?view=vs-2017 If you don't even check MSBuild logging, the cause will never be found.

Answer (score 1):

Copy project to different directory 
Go to project property change the path of virtual directory

Change iis port to 81 or other than previously used
Then compile it 
You cannot use two project with same port in iis
You can even change it to run on iisexpress 
You can’t build because of your project settings

Try creating brand new web project choosing iis