# Up-To-Date check claims missing build output since VS 2019

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

Since I am using Visual Studio 2019, some of my old projects are rebuild every time I, even though nothing changed. Build output states the following:

> Up-To-Date check: Project: ..\MyProject.vcxproj, Configuration: Debug Win32
>
> Project is not up-to-date: build output 'd:\mysolution\myproject\debug\' is missing

The mentioned output directory does exist, but with capitalization (*D:\MySolution\MyProject\Debug*)

Building the same project in Visual Studio 2017, MSBuild correctly detects when nothing has changed:

> Up-To-Date check: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Debug Win32
>
> All outputs are up-to-date.

The problematic projects are managed C++ projects, configured platform toolset is "Visual Studio 2013 (v12)".

Comment: [submit it to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduce same issue on my side for now. Could you share a sample which has the same issue so that i can reproduce and check directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

1. Clean the solution,close the solution and VS
2. Delete the .suo file(or .vs folder) and bin and obj folders
3. Open VS2019, re-ref the dlls,change ref path in .xxproj file

See this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645316/visual-studio-2015-doesnt-detect-built-project-looks-for-output-in-wrong-direc).

If the issue persists, please check if you've set the output path with an absolute path. Always the output dir should be a relative path by default:

[image]

**Update:**

Now I think I've located the cause of the issue, some mistake in your project file mess up the build process.

Please check this:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      ...
      <ProgramDataBaseFileName>$(Configuration)\</ProgramDataBaseFileName>
  <!--<ProgramDataBaseFileName>$(Configuration)\$(TargetName).pdb</ProgramDataBaseFileName>-->
      <CompileAsManaged>true</CompileAsManaged>
      <PrecompiledHeaderFile />
    </ClCompile>
```

The value of ProgramDataBaseFileName is `$(Configuration)\`, which is `debug\`. So the build process thinks there exist a build output **file** named `debug\`, but it actually doesn't exist. Then the Up-To-Date check can't work normally!

**Here is the workaround:**

So you can either comment that statement or gives it right value like `$(Configuration)\$(TargetName).pdb` instead of `$(Configuration)\` which is a path not a file.

`<!--<ProgramDataBaseFileName>$(Configuration)\</ProgramDataBaseFileName>-->` or `<ProgramDataBaseFileName>$(Configuration)\$(TargetName).pdb</ProgramDataBaseFileName>` can resolve this issue.

Note: Since the `ProgramDataBaseFileName` exists in both ItemDefinitionGroup from Debug|win32 and Release|win32, you should correct the value in **two places** in your .vcxproj file.

Comment: Tried 1 & 2 and checked the output dir (its "$(Configuration)\"). The project I'm testing with has no references (except mscorlib.dll). What do you mean by "re-ref the dlls,change ref path in .xxproj file"?

Comment: If the project has no extra references. What's the result after you've tried 1 & 2, same issue persists? If so, could you share a simple sample to help reproduce it. (I mean you can copy one project which has this issue, and delete the core code in it, we don't need personal code)

Comment: Issue persists after 1 & 2. How can I contact you for the sample? Stackoverflow does not allow me to put a link to a file share.

Comment: You can share it by one-drive or github. The one-drive link and github link is approved I think. (Don't forget to delete the personal core code)

Comment: @user2900970 I've reproduced the issue. And I'm trying to locate the cause and check if there exists a workaround. Also, I will download VS2013 to check if all managed C++ projects will cause this issue in VS2019. Any update I will share here. Thanks for your project to help me reproduce it!

Comment: @user2900970 See my update, hope it is helpful and any update feel free to let me know :)

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed the issue. I still don't know, why this wasn't a problem with Visual Studio 2017, but I assume the up-to-date-check works differently there.

Comment: Yes , it works in VS2017. I think the VS2017 should behave like VS2019 but it didn't, maybe there is difference between their up-to-date check settings.